# Exchange BufferStrategy FrameBuffer with Custom Buffer

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, bufferstrategy

I wrote a Java color buffer class that contains a 2D float array, which is the buffer.
Now I want to exchange the buffer from the BufferStrategy of my JFrame/Canvas with my buffer.
I did this by drawing each pixel of the buffer to the screen using drawLine:

```
public void exchangeBuffers(Graphics g) {
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            g.drawLine(i, j, i, j);
}
```

Now is there a better way of doing this? The performance is really low using this.

Comment: Exactly how low is the performance? Do you have any measurements or examples?

Comment: I got ~40 FPS on my Intel i7 3820 with 24GB RAM. On my Ultrabook I got something under 10 FPS.